# Laravel Schedule Not Running Update Data in the Database

Tags: laravel, docker, ansible, yaml

I have CRON job in Laravel project, it is working in my local machine and in production for more than 3 months now.

When i check it last month, the CRON job starts to failed and not working. I'am wondering whether the problem is on my dev ops codes or any ideas regarding this.

I'am using Amazon Web Services EC2 - Fargate in the deployment.

Comment: You need to try to debug it first and try to check your code if it's running perfectly without any errors because errors may come when you have a lot of data on your application.

Comment: Provide way more details please.